# strawberry perl: no File::Tail.pm. CPAN failed to install the module

Tags: perl, perl-module, tail, strawberry-perl

I'm using strawberry perl to tail a file using use `File::Tail`.

I got the error message of the following:

> Can't locate File/Tail.pm in @INC (@INC contains: c:\strawberry\perl\lib C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/strawberry/perl/
>   lib .) at tailing.perl line 5.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tailing.perl line 5.

Three packages contains lib:

- `c:\strawberry\perl\lib`
- `C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib`
- `C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib`

where `c:\strawberry\perl` is the root directory of perl installation.
I checked all the three packages, but couldn't find `File/Tail.pm`.

Used cpan install, but the installation failed.

Comment: This was just reported as a ticket to the distribution's bug queue: https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=103771  If you'd filed it when you asked the question, it might have been fixed four years ago. :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current `File::Tail` distribution on CPAN has [never passed its test suite on Windows](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=File-Tail%200.99.3). [Steffen Mueller submitted a patch](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=22903) for Windows 5 years ago, but it has never been incorporated into the distribution on CPAN.

His patch is available [here](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Attachment/274892/122654/File-Tail-0.99.4.tar.gz), and hallelujah, it works for me. Just unpack it anywhere and run the conventional

```
perl Makefile.PL
dmake
dmake test
dmake install
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the great thing about Strawberry Perl.

```
C:\Users\me > cpan File::Tail
```

Of course, I got:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/10open.t       (Wstat: 0 Tests: 6 Failed: 4)
  Failed tests:  3-6
t/20tail.t       (Wstat: 0 Tests: 3 Failed: 3)
  Failed tests:  1-3
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 7 tests but ran 3.
t/30name_change.t (Wstat: 0 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 2 tests but ran 1.
Files=3, Tests=10, 32 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr +  0.09 sys =  0.12 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 3/3 test programs. 8/10 subtests failed.
dmake.EXE:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
  MGRABNAR/File-Tail-0.99.3.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.EXE test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports MGRABNAR/File-Tail-0.99.3.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

So I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Not all modules are part of the standard module set. You should check the Perldoc Perl documentation. This contains all the ***standard*** Perl modules. If a module isn't in there, you have to install it.

As Axeman said, you can use the `cpan` command to install any module. Just type in `cpan` at the command prompt and when you get the `cpan>` prompt, type in `install File::Tail`. It should install everything for you automatically including prerequisites.

You can also look at module reviews at [CPAN Ratings](http://cpanratings.perl.org/).